# android emoji icon lib not instantiated/How to use EmojiconEditText in eclipse

Tags: android, emoji

Hello all i want to use Emoji icon for that i have added emoji_lib.jar in my project

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:id="@+id/parant_layout"

              xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.rockerhieu.emojicon.example.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_chat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_and_emos_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_attachments_chat_screen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/smiley" />


<com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
      android:id="@+id/et_message"
       android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText> 
     <!--   <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/et_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       > -->


     <!--    <requestFocus />
        </EditText>  -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_send_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/sent" />
    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_for_emoticons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/emojicons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            class="com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But it says...

```
     The following classes could not be instantiated:
        - com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText (Open Class, Show Error Log)
        See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
        Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rockerhieu.emojicon.R$drawable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconHandler.<clinit>(EmojiconHandler.java:34)
```

And my Logcat:

```
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.addonwebsolution.yarg/com.addonwebsolution.yarg.activity.NewChatThroughNotification}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.addonwebsolution.yarg.activity.NewChatThroughNotification.onCreate(NewChatThroughNotification.java:79)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  ... 11 more
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  ... 24 more
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText.onTextChanged(EmojiconEditText.java:55)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3700)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1213)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:56)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText.<init>(EmojiconEditText.java:37)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  ... 27 more
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rockerhieu.emojicon.R$drawable
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconHandler.<clinit>(EmojiconHandler.java:34)
11-03 06:02:43.398: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  ... 35 more
```

Is it requires more settings? i have added Jar file to libs folder and then add lib to build path..
Please help to solve this problem

Comment: I assume this is in the layout editor and not when you run the app?

Comment: not understanding what you say?

Comment: I'm asking if this shows in the layout editor in Eclipse/Android Studio or when you actually run the app.

Answer (score 0):

**Error inflating class com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText**

And

**Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rockerhieu.emojicon.R$drawable**

```
<com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
      android:id="@+id/et_message"
       android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Change the above code  to

```
<PackageNameAboveThisClass.EmojiconEditText
      android:id="@+id/et_message"
       android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```